# How to redirect traffic to a specific IP through a proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, routing, http-proxy

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine that for accessing a specific IP (for example n.n.n.n) I need to use a proxy (p.p.p.p:p1) but at the same time, I cannot use the proxy for the rest of the traffic on that machine.

How can I send the traffic to that specific IP through proxy and don't touch the rest?

Comment: Why not use something like FoxyProxy? If you cannot set this up in your application, you’ll need a transparent proxy.

Comment: It is a server and one of the apps needs to access that IP but other apps cannot work if all the traffic goes through that proxy. Can you please tell me more about transparent proxy in an answer?

Comment: A proxy doesn’t have to be a system-wide setting. Does this particular application also access other stuff that cannot go through the proxy? Does the application support proxies?